# How to manage selected post-formats in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type-support

```
 'supports' => array('title','author','post-formats'),
```

Now display all types of post-formats but i want to display only selected.

**like : link,audio,video**

Answer (score 1):

While the post type can add support for post formats using `'supports'` or `add_post_type_support()`, it's up to the theme to say which formats will actually have an impact on the front end.

Example:
`add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );`.